# refresh external website with new form data provide with href

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

Folks
I am in need to construct a simple < a> tag. or another such mechanism such as < form> etc

There is a third party tool that does not takes arguments in the url.

But suppose at a certain endpoint "https://example.com/ticket" there is a form that performs a search on given tickets Number. I can head over there and manually type a ticket ID and submit the form and result is retrieved. 
This tool has one input and one button

```
<input id="query" name="query" autocomplete="off" type="text">
<button> name="button" type="submit" class="btn"></button>
```

On my page I have list of tickets assign to certain users, and I am trying to construct an href link that will take the user to "https://example.com/ticket" in new window and reload the page with provide ticket ID in post method

something like following

```
<a href="https://example.com/ticket">TICKET-123</a>
```

one of the option I tried is

```
<form action="https://example.com/ticket" method="post">
    <input id="query" name="query" autocomplete="off" type="text" hidden>
    <button> name="button" type="submit" class="btn" value="TICKET-123"></button>
</form>
```

Argument in the usr such as https://example.com/ticket?id=TICKET-123 would've been sweet, but form link does not work. what am I missing

Comment: Arguments in the url are the query string for GET arguments.

Comment: However, your ability to submit a post request to the other website depends upon if they have CORS enable to allow that.  If they do not, then you will be unable to do this, without a proxy.

Comment: The modern way to do this would be to hit an API on their end, if they happen to have one. You otherwise would (as @Taplar said) not be able to submit a request on another site from your scripts.

Comment: You should use JavaScript to create the correct URL based on the button `.value`. When a `GET` URL is clicked it will load the page anew.

Comment: ... `such as https://example.com/ticket?id=TICKET-123`  in the tool you say it has `<input  … name="query" …>` so the argument in the URL would be "**query**" not "**id**" -- `https://example.com/ticket?query=TICKET-123` -- have you tried that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try something like this for the form sending a user to `search.php`

```html
<form action="search" method="get" name="searchform" target="_self">
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter your ticket number" id="ticketnumber" name="ticketnumber">
<button class="button" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

where `search.php` would contain the following

```
<?php 
  $ticketnumber = $_GET["ticketnumber"];
  header("Location: https://example.com/ticket/$ticketnumber");
  die();
?>
```

This would work if you just need to send users to an external site. As long as the pattern is like this. You then wouldn't need to reload the page if you can send the user to the URL correctly in the first instance.

Your question is a little vague but I think this approach could work because users then must input their ticket number instead of getting the inner text from the `<a>` tag. Let me know if you're looking at a different approach and please clarify how.

Also, if you didn't want to process this via PHP (I'd recommend it though because users can't see how it's done) you could go with the same form and the following

```html
<form action="example.com/ticket/" method="get" name="searchform" target="_self">
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter your ticket number" id="ticketnumber" name="ticketnumber">
<button class="button" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Or you could use `window.location.replace("https://example.com/ticket/#");` and place the ticket number where `#` is.

Comment: I am not sure what is the server side programming language this ticketing portal is using. API access is not being granted for bureaucracy purpose.
The application I am developing is using python Flask with Jinja2 templating.

Comment: What's the pattern of the URL for the ticket when you view it? You can easily use a form and PHP on your end to send a user there if it's just a URL you need.

Comment: Actually, your solution window.location.replace("https://example.com/ticket/#");  worked :-)

Comment: Brilliant, no worries. Often the simplest solution is the one.